# Recursive and non-recursive traversal of three degree tree

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, tree, tree-traversal

I'm trying to write an algorithm for inorder traversal (left, node, mid, right) of a three degree tree.

Is the below a correct algorithm for this?

```
inorder(node)
{
  if (node) {
    inorder(node->left);
    print("%d", node->value);
    if (node->mid) {
      inorder(node->mid);
      print("%d", node->value);
      inorder(node->right);
    }
    else
      inorder(node->right);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are printing the value of node twice. Also, if node is null then there should not be any else statement IMO.

Comment: Is degree=3 true for all nodes or 1<=degree<=3. You should check for existence of branches and then simply execute them.

Comment: @user568109 i want to execute this only for three degree tree ...
it works or have some problem attached with it..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're incorrectly printing the node's value twice.

You don't need to check `node->mid`, as this is checked inside `inorder(node->mid);`.

```
inorder(node)
{
  if (node)
  {
    inorder(node->left);
    print("%d ", node->value);
    inorder(node->mid);
    inorder(node->right);
  }
}
```